# Log4J different log level for each package in log4j2.xml

Tags: java, log4j2

I have a java web app with `log4j2.xml` 
I need to have a different level for each package
for example:

`com.myexample.firstmodule.*` this should be with `INFO` level
`com.myexample.secondmodule.*` this should be with `TRACE` level

I found some answers telling how to do that in `.propreties` file, but I couldn't understand how to do it with `.xml`

Anyone can help with that, please?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this

```xml
<logger name="com.myexample.firstmodule" level="INFO" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE-AUDIT" />
</logger>
<logger name="com.myexample.secondmodule" level="TRACE" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE-AUDIT" />
</logger>
```

in my config STDOUT stands for console logger and FILE-AUDIT for file logger.

Comment: Great answer, Thank you very much

Answer (score 14):

The log4j website contains detailed information about how to do this, but here's the basic example of an xml configuration they give:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
  <Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </Console>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Logger name="com.foo.Bar" level="trace">
      <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
    </Logger>
    <Root level="error">
      <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

As you can see, the `Loggers` section can contain a `Logger` tag, in which you can define the level for any package you want.

Comment: Thank you very much, exactly what i was looking for

Comment: That made all my logs from 'com.foo.Bar' with level 'trace' to be printed twice ):

Comment: Solved by adding `additivity="false"` to the loggers

Comment: The reason it prints twice is because AppenderRef is defined multiple times. If you remove AppenderRef in "com.foo.Bar", then the event will use the next AppenderRef it finds in the logger chain (ie. in this case the event falls through to the parent logger (ie. Root) which will only print once to Console).