# Flink KafkaSink connector with exactly once semantics too many logs

Tags: apache-flink

Configuring a KafkaSink from new Kafka connector API (since version 1.15) with `DeliveryGuarantee.EXACTLY_ONCE` and transactionalId prefix produce an excessive amount of logs each time a new  checkpoint is triggered.
Logs are these

```
2022-11-02 10:04:10,124 INFO  org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.sink.FlinkKafkaInternalProducer [] - Flushing new partitions
2022-11-02 10:04:10,125 INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig             [] - ProducerConfig values: 
    acks = -1
    batch.size = 16384
    bootstrap.servers = [localhost:9092]
    buffer.memory = 33554432
    client.dns.lookup = use_all_dns_ips
    client.id = producer-flink-1-24
    compression.type = none
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    delivery.timeout.ms = 120000
    enable.idempotence = true
    interceptor.classes = []
    internal.auto.downgrade.txn.commit = false
    key.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer
    linger.ms = 0
    max.block.ms = 60000
    max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 5
    max.request.size = 1048576
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metadata.max.idle.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    partitioner.class = class org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner
    receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
    reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    retries = 2147483647
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.jaas.config = null
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.login.class = null
    sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
    sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
    sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
    security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
    security.providers = null
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    socket.connection.setup.timeout.max.ms = 30000
    socket.connection.setup.timeout.ms = 10000
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
    ssl.engine.factory.class = null
    ssl.key.password = null
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.certificate.chain = null
    ssl.keystore.key = null
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.protocol = TLSv1.3
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.certificates = null
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    transaction.timeout.ms = 60000
    transactional.id = flink-1-24
    value.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer
2022-11-02 10:04:10,131 INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer              [] - [Producer clientId=producer-flink-1-24, transactionalId=flink-1-24] Overriding the default enable.idempotence to true since transactional.id is specified.
2022-11-02 10:04:10,161 INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer              [] - [Producer clientId=producer-flink-0-24, transactionalId=flink-0-24] Overriding the default enable.idempotence to true since transactional.id is specified.
2022-11-02 10:04:10,161 INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer              [] - [Producer clientId=producer-flink-0-24, transactionalId=flink-0-24] Instantiated a transactional producer.
2022-11-02 10:04:10,162 INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer              [] - [Producer clientId=producer-flink-0-24, transactionalId=flink-0-24] Overriding the default acks to all since idempotence is enabled.
2022-11-02 10:04:10,159 INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer              [] - [Producer clientId=producer-flink-1-24, transactionalId=flink-1-24] Instantiated a transactional producer.
2022-11-02 10:04:10,170 INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer              [] - [Producer clientId=producer-flink-1-24, transactionalId=flink-1-24] Overriding the default acks to all since idempotence is enabled.
2022-11-02 10:04:10,181 INFO  org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser                  [] - Kafka version: 2.8.1
2022-11-02 10:04:10,184 INFO  org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser                  [] - Kafka commitId: 839b886f9b732b15
2022-11-02 10:04:10,184 INFO  org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser                  [] - Kafka startTimeMs: 1667379850181
2022-11-02 10:04:10,185 INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.TransactionManager [] - [Producer clientId=producer-flink-0-24, transactionalId=flink-0-24] Invoking InitProducerId for the first time in order to acquire a producer ID
2022-11-02 10:04:10,192 INFO  org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser                  [] - Kafka version: 2.8.1
2022-11-02 10:04:10,192 INFO  org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser                  [] - Kafka commitId: 839b886f9b732b15
2022-11-02 10:04:10,192 INFO  org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser                  [] - Kafka startTimeMs: 1667379850192
2022-11-02 10:04:10,209 INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.TransactionManager [] - [Producer clientId=producer-flink-1-24, transactionalId=flink-1-24] Invoking InitProducerId for the first time in order to acquire a producer ID
2022-11-02 10:04:10,211 INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata                            [] - [Producer clientId=producer-flink-0-24, transactionalId=flink-0-24] Cluster ID: MCY5mzM1QWyc1YCvsO8jag
2022-11-02 10:04:10,216 INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.TransactionManager [] - [Producer clientId=producer-flink-0-24, transactionalId=flink-0-24] Discovered transaction coordinator ubuntu:9092 (id: 0 rack: null)
2022-11-02 10:04:10,233 INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata                            [] - [Producer clientId=producer-flink-1-24, transactionalId=flink-1-24] Cluster ID: MCY5mzM1QWyc1YCvsO8jag
2022-11-02 10:04:10,241 INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.TransactionManager [] - [Producer clientId=producer-flink-1-24, transactionalId=flink-1-24] Discovered transaction coordinator ubuntu:9092 (id: 0 rack: null)
2022-11-02 10:04:10,345 INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.TransactionManager [] - [Producer clientId=producer-flink-0-24, transactionalId=flink-0-24] ProducerId set to 51 with epoch 0
2022-11-02 10:04:10,346 INFO  org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.sink.KafkaWriter            [] - Created new transactional producer flink-0-24
2022-11-02 10:04:10,353 INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.TransactionManager [] - [Producer clientId=producer-flink-1-24, transactionalId=flink-1-24] ProducerId set to 52 with epoch 0
2022-11-02 10:04:10,354 INFO  org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.sink.KafkaWriter            [] - Created new transactional producer flink-1-24
```

`ProducerConfig` values log is repeated for each new producer created (based on sink parallelism level).

Configuring checkpoint interval to 10 or 15 seconds, I lose valuable job logs.
There is a way to disable these logs without setting WARN level?

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47051224/log4j-different-log-level-for-each-package-in-log4j2-xml